# Why dynamic scheduling is faster than static scheduling in openmp

Tags: c++, openmp, codeblocks

I am learning parallel programming, and I am trying to figure out the difference between dynamic and static scheduling.

As I understand till now the static should be faster than the dynamic because the chunks in the static are computed and scheduled to threads during compilation not during the run time. But I execute the program below and the static time results bigger than the dynamic time...Why does this happen? Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(a,b,c,nthreads,chunk) private(i,tid)
{
 tid = omp_get_thread_num();
 if (tid == 0){
 nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
 printf("Number of threads = %d\n", nthreads);
 }
 printf("Thread %d starting...\n",tid);
 #pragma omp for schedule(static,chunk)
 for (i=0; i<N; i++){
 c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
 printf("Thread %d: c[%d]= %f\n",tid,i,c[i]);
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really hard to assess the performance of any piece of code, especially such a short piece one. There are many factors that contribute, starting at your specific machine. How many times did you run the code? How long was each run? You need good statistics to be able to tell definitively that something is faster/slower than something else. Even then, the same might not be true for someone else. What processor are you using, how many cores does it have, and how many threads are you scheduling?

A lot can also depends on your choice of `chunk` size. Perhaps the choice you're making is not optimal. If you want to find out more, perform a sweep of various values of `chunk` and benchmark the performance. That being said, the probable reason for your observation is that your system is being utilized differently during the two tests. Dynamic scheduling adapts better to runtime conditions.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Now I understand that there are other condition that influence the time of the execution.